# Error in Viewmodelhelper.createfromViewmodel method

Tags: mdriven

In MVC 4 web application using Mdriven framework version is 7.0.12531 to access data from SQL 2014 express.

We are encountering error while trying to get data using viewmodel xml (Which contains OCL) error is (
"bughuntinfo internaleval:83  es seems fineObject reference not set to an instance of an object.")

> at Eco.Ocl.Impl.OclImplBase.InternalEvaluate(String oclExpression, IElement rootElement, IClassifier context, SubscriberPair subscriberPair, IExternalVariableList variableList)
> at Eco.Ocl.Impl.OclServiceImpl.BaseEvaluate(IElement root, IClassifier Context, IExternalVariableList vars, String expression)
> at Eco.Ocl.Impl.OclServiceImpl.Evaluate(IElement root, String expression, IExternalVariableList vars)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelClass.CollectObjectsForCOnstraintsCheck(IObjectList allobjects)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.UpdateErrorsFromConstraints(List`1 errors, List`1 warnings, List`1 info, ISubscriber subscriber) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelClass.ModernQueryPlanExpressionsRunToFindMissing(IElement root, Boolean runallnotsparse, Boolean doStructureNotLevel) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.ModernQueryPlanLoop(IFetchConsolidationService fetchconsolidation, Boolean doStructureNotLevel) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.ModernQueryPlanExecute(Action doFirstThingInsideQueryPlanAction) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.<EnsureSpanFetch>b__42_0() at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.WrapTaskInStandardExceptionHandling(Action task) at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.PerformTaskNowIfInAsyncThread(Action task) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.EnsureSpanFetch() at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass156_0.<SetElement>b__0() at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.WrapTaskInStandardExceptionHandling(Action task) at Eco.Services.Impl.AsyncSupportServiceImpl.PerformTaskNowIfInAsyncThread(Action task) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.SetElement(IEcoObject obj) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModel.set_RootObject(IEcoObject value) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.VMClass.UpdateContent(IElement value, Boolean skipCheckOfBeingRoot) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.VMClass.set_Content(IElement value) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.VMClass..ctor(VMClassDescriptor vMClassDescriptor, IEcoServiceProvider sp, VMClass ownedby, IElement content, IExternalVariableList variables, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.VMClassDescriptor.CreateInstance(IEcoServiceProvider sp, IEcoObject iEcoObject, IExternalVariableList iExternalVariableList, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.ActOnVMClassFromViewModelRTCreator_WithOptionalVMClassSupplied(VMClass optionalVMClass, VMClassFromViewModelRTCreator x, IEcoObject root, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.ActOnVMClassFromViewModelRTCreator(VMClassFromViewModelRTCreator x, IEcoObject root, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate) at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.CreateFromViewModel(Type esType, EcoSpace es, IEcoObject root, ViewModelRTCreator vmc_c, GetVMClassTypeDelegate creator, IViewUICreator externalViewUICreator, Action`1 initViewModelAction, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate, IEcoServiceProvider spToUse)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.CreateFromViewModel(Type esType, EcoSpace es, IEcoObject root, ViewModelRTCreator vmc_c, GetVMClassTypeDelegate creator, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate, IEcoServiceProvider spToUse)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.CreateFromViewModel(EcoSpace es, IEcoObject root, ViewModelRTCreator vmc_c, GetVMClassTypeDelegate creator, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.CreateFromViewModel(String viewmodelName, EcoSpace es, IEcoObject root, GetVMClassTypeDelegate creator, Boolean useDisplayQueueDrivenAutoPopulate)
> at Eco.ViewModel.Runtime.ViewModelHelper.CreateFromViewModel(String viewmodelName, EcoSpace es, IEcoObject root)

Answer (score 0):

The logic tries to interpret constraints but seems to run into problems: UpdateErrorsFromConstraints

Does your model validate without errors? I suspect ill formed constraints in ocl.

Comment: Yes checked model errors here is screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQts.png  it worked fine until last week when i update mdriven from 12013 to 7.0.12534 –

Comment: Can you get the break in the debugger and see the InternalEvaluate expression param? 
The error happens during the queryplanner doing the fetch job - email us something to repeat at support @ mdriven.net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checked model errors it has no errors[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBQts.png)